# .net html to image with managed code

Tags: .net, html, image, service, screenshot

I  have service which converts HTML to image and sends back.

At present I am using WebBrowser control to do that. But it is far from perfect. During peak hours service crashes or gives Null reference exception. Also it is not lightweight on memory. I looking for lightweight managed option to this job.

Kindly let me know for any open source project or for any other managed control which will do this job.

Update:
I have very simple HTML to render. It is only with table, paragraph and stylesheet for font and background-color. There is not Javascript, element float or other complex layout.

Comment: You do realize that you are asking for another Browser, right? With all the involved complexities and incompatibilities.

Comment: check question for update. Not sure if I am asking for another Browser, but another HTML render-er.

Comment: Yes, but HTML-renderer = 90% off a Browser, and 99.9% off the incompatibilities.

Comment: Anyway, you're not going to find anything simple or small. But you can probably do better than the IE-based WebControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally settled on WebBrowser control due to not so valid HTML available at my end.

I should mention following post which should solve problem for other guys who got valid HTML. It mentions few open source and paid controls.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/managed-html-rendering.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Awesomium](http://labs.awesomium.com/capturing-web-pages-with-c-net/)

```
using System;
using AwesomiumSharp;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace AwesomiumSharpBasic
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            // Display some informative message. Loading the page
            // may  take a while depending on your internet
            // connection speed.
            Console.WriteLine( "Getting a 1024x768 snapshot" +
                "of http://www.awesomium.com ..." );

            // Create a WebView.
            // WebView implements IDisposable. You can dispose and
            // destroy the view by calling WebView.Close().
            // Here we demonstrate wrapping it in a using statement.
            using ( WebView webView =
                    WebCore.CreateWebView( 1024, 768 ) )
            {
                // Variable used to announce
                // that the page has loaded.
                bool finishedLoading = false;

                // Load a page in the view.
                webView.LoadURL( "http://www.awesomium.com" );
                // Handle the LoadCompleted event to monitor
                // page loading.
                webView.LoadCompleted += ( sender, e ) =>
                {
                    finishedLoading = true;
                };

                // Wait for the page to load.
                while ( !finishedLoading )
                {
                    Thread.Sleep( 100 );
                    // WebCore provides an Auto-Update feature
                    // for UI applications. A console application
                    // has no UI and no synchronization context
                    // so we need to manually call Update here.
                    WebCore.Update();

                }
                // Render to a pixel buffer and save the buffer
                // to a .png image.
                webView.Render().SaveToPNG( "result.png", true );
            }

            // Start the application associated with .png files
            // and display the file.
            Process.Start( "result.png" );

            // Shut down Awesomium before exiting.
            WebCore.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: current Awesomium version have a [different syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15512249/1020222).

Answer (score 1):

Try [WebKit .Net](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I believe you are pointing towards WebKitBrowser control. It looks similar to Webbrowser control with event. I was looking for something like object.GetImage(HTML). Let me know if you are talking about some other control.